# How can I destroy my Session in my Rails API, when I don't have an id for the sessions/:id(.:format)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, http-delete

I don't have a model Session. There are no id's, rows, data, etc.

I have...

```
module Api
    module V1
        class SessionsController < ApplicationController
            include Api::V1::SessionsHelper
            respond_to :json
            skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

            def create
                @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
                if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
                    token = User.new_remember_token
                    sign_in @user, token
                    render json: {status: :success, token: token, user_id: @user.id }
                else
                    render json: {status: :failure, error: "Authentication Failed"}
                end
            end

            def destroy
                token = User.digest([:session][:token])
                @user = User.find_by(remember_token: [:session][:token])
                if @user
                    sign_out
                    render json: {status: :success}
                else
                    render json: {status: :failure, error: "Could not find user to sign out"}
                end

            end
        end
    end
end
```

Now in PostMan/iOS, I can create a new session by sending a POST to api/v1/sessions with json that looks like

```
{
    "session": 
        {
            "email": "v@v.com",
            "password": "vvvvvv"
        }
}
```

This will send back a token to the caller to be stored on the device, and the hashed token will be stored along with the User model.

However, if I want to destroy the session and send in...

```
{
    "session": 
        {
            "token": "34Y6hFDA8LyVNexlKHxwwQ"
        }   
}
```

I can't do this because the rake routes has...

```
api_v1_sessions POST   /api/v1/sessions(.:format)                        api/v1/sessions#create {:format=>"json"}
api_v1_session DELETE /api/v1/sessions/:id(.:format)                    api/v1/sessions#destroy {:format=>"json"}
```

/api/v1/sessions/:id(.:format). I don't have an id to pass in. I just want to be able to DELETE at /api/v1/sessions, pass in the unhashed token, and then my controller can hash it, search for the token in the DB, and remove it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you access the id via `[:session][:id]`?  Is the id included in the params?

Comment: No. The session doesn't really have an id, because I am not saving anything... there is no Session model. Session is just like a dummy, to create and destroy tokens.

Comment: Very curious.  What if you just passed in a dummy id then, for the route's sake?

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not use the `id` parameter, you can just set it to anything in the URL, like:

```
/api/v1/sessions/dummy
```

A test with curl would look like this:

```
curl -X DELETE -d "session[token]=token-here" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions/dummy
```

Answer (score -1):

you can to change in routes.rb
resources to resource

example:
resource :sessions, only: %i[create destroy show]